# Add a column with a consecutive string to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

**Objective:**

I have a dataset, df that looks like this:

```
   End                      Duration

   1/5/2020 1:50:00 AM       500
   1/6/2020 2:00:00 AM       450
   1/7/2020 1:00:00 AM       800
```

**My desired outcome:**

```
  Username                  Duration

  Tanisha                    500
  Tanisha                    450
  Tanisha                    800
```

I would like to replace the 'End' column with the same string value for each Duration row.
  (I have over 110,000 rows)

**Dput:**

```
structure(list(End = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1/5/2020 1:50:00 AM", 
"1/6/2020 2:00:00 AM", "1/7/2020 1:00:00 AM"), class = "factor"), 
Duration = c(500L, 450L, 800L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

**I am thinking that I can do an assignment such as:**

```
 df[["End"]] <- Tanisha
```

But how do I retain the Duration column in the process. I am not sure if I should use mutate.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: `df$User <- "Tanisha"` ?

Comment: If you really want to use `dplyr`, you can do `df %>% mutate(Username = "Tanisha") %>% select(Username, Duration)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, can't really find a relevant post for this so adding as an answer.

You could do add a new column directly by doing.

```
df$Username <- "Tanisha"

#                  End Duration Username
#1 1/5/2020 1:50:00 AM      500  Tanisha
#2 1/6/2020 2:00:00 AM      450  Tanisha
#3 1/7/2020 1:00:00 AM      800  Tanisha
```

---

Or with `dplyr` there are multiple ways :

```
tibble::add_column(df, Username = 'Tanisha')
```

Or

```
dplyr::transmute(df, Username = 'Tanisha', Duration)
```

Comment: Thank you , in order to change a column name from one to another, I can use dplyr for this right? (while preserving the dataframe)

Comment: Yes, there is `rename_at`, `rename_all` or `set_names` to change column name.

Comment: I need to rename a column while preserving my dataset and this isn't working: df %>% rename(
    Aggregation = Duration)

Comment: it keeps telling me Duration is not found, however, this is the name I wish to create or change the Aggregation column to @ronak

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
df$Username <- 'Tanisha'
```